# Is every computable function the time complexity of some function?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

Considering the recent question "[Is there an algorithm whose time complexity is between polynomial time and exponential time?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/147873/is-there-an-algorithm-whose-time-complexity-is-between-polynomial-time-and-expon)", some commenters observed that merely providing a function with growth strictly between polynomial and exponential answers the question, because it is easy to construct an algorithm with the required complexity. For example, if you chose $f(n) = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$, then the following algorithm has complexity $O(f(n))$:

1. Compute $x = 2^{\sqrt{n}}$.
2. Increment an integer variable until you reach $x$.

Sounds easy - but for many functions step 1 takes longer than step 2. For example, let $f(n)$ be the value of $A(n, n)$ mod 37. Assuming that this requires actually computing $A(n, n)$ (and there is not some theorem like "$A(n, n)$ is always divisible by $37$") then the procedure above will not produce an algorithm with the required complexity.

Of course, since this $f$ is $O(1)$, it's easy to construct an algorithm with the required complexity. But it's conceivable that there is some slow-growing hard-to-compute function which does not have the same "cheat".

My intuition, however, is that there is a cleverer technique that will always work. Is there?

Comment: (It should not be too hard to construct a *procedure* to fit. An *algorithm' is defined as a solution to a problem. Non-monotone functions may be less useful.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_function, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51082/14578